# Pass final positional argument in a curried function to the last parameter available

Tags: python, functional-programming, currying

Given a simple curried function

```
import toolz

@toolz.curry
def mklist(x, y, z):
    return [x, y, z]
```

obviously calling `mklist(x=1, y=2)(z=3)` works.

What I would like to be able to do is to call the function like so: `mklist(x=1, y=2)(3)`, where z gets bound to 3.

This errors with `TypeError: mklist() got multiple values for argument 'x'` since passing a positional argument apparently tries to assign the argument to the first paramter (x).

How can it be made so that the final positional argument of a curried function gets passed to the last remaining parameter?

Comment: I don't think keyword arguments mix well with non-keyword arguments.  You ought to be able to write `mklist(1, 2)(3)`.

Comment: I believe you could try to implement something like that by meta-programming with [inspect and signatures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature.parameters), but since you already use another tool, it may be hard to achieve.